# How to resolve 'Unexpected Token =' error when using Swagger API in Node.js and running 'npm start'?

Tags: node.js, swagger, node-modules

Getting error while npm start :
Unexpected Token = error at at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)

error seems to be in file :
\node_modules@swagger-api\apidom-core\cjs\serializers\value\ast\ephemeral-array.cjs:6
type = 'EphemeralArray';

i am using node version 10.24.1 , npm 6.14.12..

is there any solution without updating node .

Comment: There might be an issue of json in your bearer that is why you may be facing it.

Comment: What are the versions of Swagger-related packages in your `package.json`? Can you also post a [minimal code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Node.js version 10 is [end-of-life](https://endoflife.date/nodejs) and unmaintained. Can you try the current version, e.g. 18 or 20?

Comment: i am using 0.69.3 version of swagger-api